# How can i Check if <object> failed to load?

Tags: javascript, html, activex

I have the following code:

```
document.getElementById("launcherDiv").innerHTML = 
"<object id='launcher' 
classid='CLSID:17E88883-3488-46B8-BE4D-30568888855' 
codebase='Helper.CAB#version=8,8,8,88'>
</object>";
```

Let say the download/installing failed,
How can I know this? depending of it that I can't know how much time it supposed to take..

If I will check in a loop how can I know when to end?

previously I used to define the  tag inside the HTML and it waiting until the installation finished or failed.
But now I need delay loading of this ActiveX so I can't use this

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Depending on your object, you could regularly check its width.

Comment: Why not add an onload attribute to your object and then call a function which does something on successful load?

Comment: @AshwinSingh I'm not familiar with onload attribute to <object> tag, Can you give an example?

Comment: @DorCohen some objects have a width only when loaded. You can easily test if it works in your case.

Comment: @dystroy the width doesn't help me because case of failure is equal to case of loading

Answer (score 4):

If object tag is failed to load then it will render inner HTML between tag. For example

```
<object data="my/file/path.pdf">Object not supported</object>
```

If object fails then it will show inner text i.e. "Object not supported"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
    var iv = setInterval(function () {
    if (document.all["launcher"].readyState == 4) {
    clearInterval(iv)
    alert("Object loaded")
    }
    }, 100);
```

What it does is set an interval which checks the readystate every 100 seconds and if the object has loaded it alerts.

Comment: Thanks for trying but it doesn't help me because there isn't failure state, Can I know if the download failed?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post but I was trying something like this my self. 
In the object tag you can do something else inside it.
For example I was making a music site and If the custom player didnt load I wanted the audio tag to take over.

example:

```
<object>
    <load customplayer> <!--==If this fails do the next line ==-->
          <audio>
                load song
          </audio>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the (first) anchor in an object that successfully loaded embedded content and the **fallback content** (first) anchor in an object that did *not* successfully load are the dimensions of the element. So all you have to do is determine your policy of the element you use for fallback (this is very likely an anchor element though some people might still support Flash as fallback content) and then target that element and get it's `height` in example; **if the height is greater than 0 the object element did not successfully load**.

```
var o = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
console.log(o[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height);
```